boost::process::async_pipe or pipe for inter process communication
I need to do inter process messaging with named pipes. 
I know async_pipe can be used for named pipe's. 
But when i try to use async_pipe my program just stuck in io_context::run() on read 
Why is that? can i even use them for inter process communication this way?
I tried to find information other than stdout/stdin redirection, but had no luck.
Here is my program
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/process.hpp"


std::string create_named_pipe_name(const std::string& name)
{
    return R"(\\.\pipe\)" + name;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    asio::io_context io, io2;
    bp::async_pipe p1(io, create_named_pipe_name("p"));
    bp::async_pipe p2(io2, create_named_pipe_name("p"));

    std::string messageToSend = "CCC";
    std::vector<char> x(3, '*');
    
    
    boost::asio::async_write(p1, boost::asio::buffer(messageToSend),
        [&messageToSend](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size)
        {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "Sent message: " << messageToSend << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Failed to write to pipe: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
    
    boost::asio::async_read(p2, boost::asio::buffer(x), [&x](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size)
        {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "Received message: " << std::string(x.data(), size) << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Failed to read from pipe: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });

    std::thread([&io]
    {
            io.run();
    }).join();
    auto t2 = std::thread([&io2]
        {
            io2.run();
        });

    t2.join();
}

output:
Sent message: CCC


you immediately join the first thread thereby preventing the second thread from starting?

no, second thread is running, io_context::run() ends after executing write

Why even have the threads? thread(f).join() is exactly equivalent to f();¹
io.run();
io2.run();


I'd simplify to remove the unnecessary second context. Both io objects can happily share the same one.

Next, you can not create the same pipe twice. I'm not on windows, but on POSIX it fails with the expected
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::process::v1::process_error>'
  what():  mkfifo() failed: File exists

In contrast, this works: Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace bp   = boost::process;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    asio::io_context io;
    bp::async_pipe   p(io, R"(\\.\pipe\p)");

    std::string outbuf = "CCC", inbuf(3, '*');

    async_write(p, asio::buffer(outbuf), [](error_code ec, size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Sent: " << size << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });

    async_read(p, asio::buffer(inbuf), [&inbuf](error_code ec, size_t /*size*/) {
        std::cout << "Received: " << quoted(inbuf) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });

    io.run();
}

It does not look like the library has a constructor to open an existing named pipe, so you'd have to open it manually, and then adopt (assign() or similar) the handle.

¹ modulo unhandled exceptions

regarding the last hint: https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html mentions named pipes: "For example, to perform asynchronous operations on a named pipe, the following object may be created:"
